# Drop table and temporary tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tablespace

I'm using oracle 11g and i have 3 tables,

when i performed **truncate** on the first table no changes happened on the TEMP table space,
also when i performed **delete** on the second table no changes happened on the TEMP table space,  .
But when i performed **drop** on the third table the TEMP  table space increased from 0MB to 1MB

Wy dropping table affects on the TEMP table space?

Answer (score 0):

*During table creation, some extents are allocated, i.e. some spaces in some tablespaces are reserved.*

*`drop` is the opposite operation of `create`, and when a `drop` command issued with `purge` option, the allocated space is released for a regular, non-temporary table. There's no need a `purge` option declaration for a temporary table for deallocation.*

*During `delete` or `truncate` operations, table stands as it is and no deallocation occurs.*